# A smooth function with derivatives of all orders bounded is sine function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inequality, entire-functions

Given $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is a smooth real function, $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$.

For all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, we have
$$|f(x)|\le 1,\ \left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)\right|\le 1, $$

prove that $f(x)=\sin x$.

This is not a homework problem. Are there any proves or references to this? How strong the condition that derivatives of all orders bounded is? I can only prove that $f$ is analytic and could be seen as an entire function with order $1$ of growth on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Someone else asked lots of this type of question a couple of months back. But I don't know how to search for or find those questions...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: You are probably thinking of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4630409/42969,  this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4630788/42969, and this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4631046/42969 from February.

Comment: @MartinR yes those are the ones. So this question is also very closely related then: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863239/if-f-is-a-smooth-real-valued-function-on-real-line-such-that-f0-1-and-f